# Measuring effective bandwidth on CUDA

Tags: performance, cuda, cublas

So I want to know how to calculate the total memory effective bandwidth for:

```
cublasSdot(handle, M, devPtrA, 1, devPtrB, 1, &curesult);
```

where that function belows to `cublas_v2.h`

That function runs in 0.46 ms, and the vectors are `10000 * sizeof(float)`

Am I having `((10000 * 4) / 10^9 )/0.00046 = 0.086 GB/s`?

I'm wondering about it because I don't know what is inside the cublasSdot function, and I don't know if it is necesary.

Comment: How do you measue the time? 10000 is too small for benchmark. Try 1,000,000+ instead.

Comment: The time is not real, I want to know if that way is OK, supposing a "true time"... I just wanna know what is the size of the input and the size of the output?, or I need to know something about the code inside the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, the size of the input data is 10000 * 4 * 2 since you have 2 input vectors, and the size of the output data is 4. The effective bandwidth should be about 0.172 GB/s.

Basically `cublasSdot()` does nothing much more than computing.
Profile result shows `cublasSdot()` invokes 2 kernels to compute the result. An extra 4-bytes device-to-host mem transfer is also invoked if the pointer mode is `CUBLAS_POINTER_MODE_HOST`, which is the default mode for cublas lib.

Comment: suppose I have a function "foo(param1, param2, param3)" where param1 and param2 are vectors and param3 is a float... Now inside the function I have many calls to different cublas functions just using that parameters I mention... The total effective bandwidth is the sum of all the cublas calls? Or I just have to compute the time spent in the function foo and consider the inputs and output that belows to the function foo?

Comment: @facunvd: The latter should be used if you just want to show the effecitve BW of your function `foo()` to others. When you optimize your function `foo()` for higher performance, you may need to dig into the function and measure each cublas call.

Comment: Let me see, I'll be more precise. I'm developing a library wich contains differents numerical methods, each of that is using many cublas calls, and I want to show the effective bandwidth of each. So you are saying me that I must measure the time of the function "congujate gradient()" and compute the effective bandwidth using the size of the matrix A and vector B and considering the output of the vector X, right?

Comment: @facunvd yes, measuring the effective BW of a function does not require the knowledge of the implementation detail of that function.

Answer (score 0):

If kernel time is in ms then a multiplication factor of 1000 is necessary. 
That results in 86 GB/s.

As an example refer to example provide by NVIDIA for Matrix Transpose
at http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/transpose/doc/MatrixTranspose.pdf

On Last Page entire code is present. The way the Effective Bandwidth is computed is 2.*1000*mem_size/(1024*1024*1024)/(Time in ms)